# Arranging in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

---

I have to create a character page for a mmorpg, the page should have a character image `130x130px` and the belonging items `32x32px` inside a parent of `col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output might not be exactly the same as picture but it is close.

HTML

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                 <div class="beta32"></div> 
                 <div class="beta32"></div> 
                 <div class="beta32"></div> 
                 <div class="beta32"></div>           
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="alpha130"></div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                             <div class="beta32"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                             <div class="beta32"></div>
                        </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                 <div class="beta32"></div> 
                 <div class="beta32"></div> 
                 <div class="beta32"></div> 
                 <div class="beta32"></div>           
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gn0mp8oz/4/)

Comment: At least I have something to begin with, thank you. I'll wait a few days for a  better answer if I won't find one, I'll mark this as accepted.